# how to pass variable one class to other class by method in objective c

Tags: objective-c

let for consider the code

```
one.h
#import "historyViewController.h"

int isItfsa;


one.m
     -(IBAction)homeHistory:(id)sender{
            isItfsa = 0;
            historyViewController *hisVController = [[historyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"historyViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self presentModalViewController:hisVController animated:YES];
            [hisVController release];
        }
```

But when i receive it does not print //0

but in 2nd class two.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"isItfsa=%@",isItfsa); //isItfsa=null
}
```

it is print null ,but why? and how i can pass the value from one class to another class by method.

Comment: Clarify your question. What do you mean by "passing value from one class to another by method"? Easy answer would be "create a method parameter",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null is the same value as zero. It writes "null" because you don't tell it to write an integer, you are telling it to write an object.

Your code:

`NSLog(@"isItfsa=%@",isItfsa)` (write `isItfsa` as object)

It should be:

`NSLog(@"isItfsa=%i",isItfsa)` (write `isItfsa` as integer)

Answer (score 2):

isItfsa is defined by your code as an int, which is not an object. Your NSLog is formatted for printing an object using `%@`. If the int value is zero, then trying to print it as an object will yield (null).

Your print statement should be `NSLog(@"isItfsa=%d",isItfsa);`

Comment: Why %d for an integer? That's just another bug.

Comment: %i works too.  Just following this documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Ah, you are right. I was under the impression that %d means double. Sometimes it's good to revisit the documentation :)

Comment: Apparently it does, judging by the other specifies. But double is the default for int in this case.

Comment: In this case %d probably means decadic integer, because %o is octal and %x hexadecimal.